# How to open flutter app from background using alarm manager?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement alarm clock functionality. I tried to use `alarm manager` and `workmanager` with delayed timings in order to open the app from the background, but it seems that there is no way to do this, using those packages.

Comment: No, it doesn't.